# How to automatically change a buffer terminal name?

Tags: terminal, terminal-buffer

I have a small `.bat` file to open Vim along with a terminal running an `IPython` console:

```
@echo off
call C:\Users\myname\Miniconda3\condabin\activate.bat C:\Users\myname\Miniconda3\envs\myenv
gvim -c "vert botright terminal C:\Users\myname\Miniconda3\condabin\conda.bat activate myenv  &&echo Conda env:%CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV%  &&ipython"
```

I am fairly happy, but the name of the terminal buffer is fairly annoying:

```
C:\Users\myname\Miniconda3\condabin\conda.bat activate myenv...
```

Hence, I manually change the name of such a terminal by putting the focus on the terminal buffer and by issuing `<c-W>:file IPYTHON` but this is very boring and error prone.

A solution would be to automatically run the command `:file IPYTHON` after I launched `:terminal` but from the documentation that does not seems to be possible.

How can I solve my problem then? Shall I modify my `.vimrc` file?
If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of executing the command `:terminal`, we can use the function `term_start` which provides us with several optional options, one of which lets us set the buffer name.

From `:h term_start`:

```
term_start({cmd} [, {options}])         *term_start()*
        Open a terminal window and run {cmd} in it.
        <snip>         
        There are extra options:
           "term_name"       name to use for the buffer name, instead
                     of the command name.
           <snip>
```

Using the above, we can refactor OP's batch script accordingly:

```
@echo off
call C:\Users\myname\Miniconda3\condabin\activate.bat C:\Users\myname\Miniconda3\envs\myenv
gvim -c "vert botright call term_start('C:\\Users\\myname\\Miniconda3\\condabin\\conda.bat activate myenv && echo Conda env:%CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV% && ipython', {'term_name': 'IPython'})"
```

Comment: Solved! Thanks!